# How to reference a database column in rails active record interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Really confused.

I've been reading through the rails guide and there seem to be difference ways to reference a column in rails. Sometimes it's as a string eg

```
Client.select("viewable_by, locked")
```

and sometimes with a colon at the beginning

```
Client.select(:name).uniq
```

When do I decide which to use? Are these interchangeable?

Comment: They are interchangeable. i guess main focus should be the query.. if query is same for both. you dont need to worry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a string, it will be injected into the sql statement, which allows you to do some advanced SQL-y stuff, like

```
select("count(name) as name_count, nvl(price, 'N/A')")
```

(this is just an example, mashing some stuff together)

If you want to select some columns, I would always use symbols or an array of symbols, like

```
Client.select(:viewable_by, :locked)
```

So in short: yes they are interchangeable, the string will not be parsed, just injected into the SQL statement, which allows you do some more advanced stuff if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are interchangeable.  They return the same result - i.e an ActiveRecord Relation containing instances of models with only the fields you requested set.

```
Client.select("viewable_by, locked") 
=> [#<Client id: nil, viewable_by: "admin", locked: true>]

Client.select(:viewable_by, :locked) 
=> [#<Client id: nil, viewable_by: "admin", locked: true>]
```

I've made up the responses but you get the idea.

If you simply wanted an array of the names I'd use pluck instead:
`Client.pluck(:name).uniq`

Comment: OK. That's a relief. i thought I was missing something. Thanks